# rviz crashes on mouse up event

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need some help debugging rviz crashes. I am publishing a `MarkerArray` with a set of `LIST_LIST` markers (that connect InteractiveMarkers). On each `POSE_UPDATE` event from an `InteractiveMarker` i remove the old lines and redraw them. Randomly (but often) rviz crashes, after moving and `InteractiveMarker` AND lifting the mouse button. I suspect this happens when rviz redraws the lines to keep them aligned to the viewer.

Does anybody have any hints on debugging this or are there any known race conditions between InteractiveMarker and Marker?

I now solved the problem by using arrows (without heads) instead of the lines, but a real solution would be nice. The stacktrace is listed below.

```
#0  0x00000000400a2c5e in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fffed6cbfb9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/nvidia-387/libnvidia-glcore.so.387.34
#2  0x00007fffed6d2b14 in ?? () from /usr/lib/nvidia-387/libnvidia-glcore.so.387.34
#3  0x00007fffed29ba95 in ?? () from /usr/lib/nvidia-387/libnvidia-glcore.so.387.34
#4  0x00007fffb4f7c9c5 in Ogre::GLRenderSystem::_render(Ogre::RenderOperation const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.9.0/RenderSystem_GL.so.1.9.0
#5  0x00007ffff39667f7 in Ogre::SceneManager::renderSingleObject(Ogre::Renderable*, Ogre::Pass const*, bool, bool, Ogre::HashedVector<Ogre::Light*> const*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.9.0
#6  0x00007ffff3990fb9 in Ogre::QueuedRenderableCollection::acceptVisitorGrouped(Ogre::QueuedRenderableVisitor*) const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.9.0
#7  0x00007ffff3991095 in Ogre::QueuedRenderableCollection::acceptVisitor(Ogre::QueuedRenderableVisitor*, Ogre::QueuedRenderableCollection::OrganisationMode) const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.9.0
#8  0x00007ffff394f8df in Ogre::SceneManager::renderBasicQueueGroupObjects(Ogre::RenderQueueGroup*, Ogre::QueuedRenderableCollection::OrganisationMode) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.9.0
#9  0x00007ffff394f757 in Ogre::SceneManager::renderVisibleObjectsDefaultSequence() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.9.0
#10 0x00007ffff3965474 in Ogre::SceneManager::_renderScene(Ogre::Camera*, Ogre::Viewport*, bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.9.0
#11 0x00007ffff39a1f51 in Ogre::Camera::_renderScene(Ogre::Viewport*, bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.9.0
#12 0x00007ffff394677a in Ogre::RenderTarget::_updateViewport(Ogre::Viewport*, bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.9.0
#13 0x00007ffff39465cb in Ogre::RenderTarget::_updateAutoUpdatedViewports(bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.9.0
#14 0x00007ffff394611e in Ogre::RenderTarget::updateImpl() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.9.0
#15 0x00007ffff3946ac4 in Ogre::RenderTarget::update(bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.9.0
#16 0x00007ffff39f6e5f in Ogre::RenderSystem::_updateAllRenderTargets(bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.9.0
#17 0x00007ffff3b0d4ba in Ogre::Root::_updateAllRenderTargets() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.9.0
#18 0x00007ffff3b0d5a0 in Ogre::Root::renderOneFrame() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.9.0
#19 0x00007ffff7b4be8e in rviz::VisualizationManager::onUpdate() () from /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librviz.so
#20 0x00007ffff1eb9d2a in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#21 0x00007ffff1ec65c8 in QTimer::timerEvent(QTimerEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#22 0x00007ffff1ebabb3 in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#23 0x00007ffff746405c in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#24 0x00007ffff7469516 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#25 0x00007ffff1e8b38b in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#26 0x00007ffff1ee05ed in QTimerInfoList::activateTimers() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#27 0x00007ffff1ee0af1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#28 0x00007ffff13e2197 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#29 0x00007ffff13e23f0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#30 0x00007ffff13e249c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#31 0x00007ffff1ee17cf in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#32 0x00007ffff1e88b4a in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#33 0x00007ffff1e90bec in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#34 0x0000000000400c99 in main ()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279956/rviz-crashes-on-mouse-up-event/) by [MatthiasLoebach](https://answers.ros.org/users/32823/matthiasloebach/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like [ros-visualization/rviz#1082](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1082) to me.

Backtrace is almost identical.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0